# JQ output not correctly assinging to variable

Tags: bash, shell

Below jq query output comes correctly.

```sh
ROUTE_ID= jq -r '.[][]? | select(.pattern? == "*test.com/testcards/email/*").id' route.json
```

route.json file contains a json output.

But echo "this is route $ROUTE_ID" or echo "this is route $ROUTE_ID does not return value for $ROUTE_ID"

Comment: your code is not valid. You probably mean `route_id=$(jq ... )`. You can use shellcheck.net to debug your script

Comment: @Aserre Acually the code is valid. Shellcheck emits a warning, but it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are currently doing is setting the environment variable ROUTE_ID to nothing for the execution of jq, eg:

```
MY_ENV=abc command
```

Will set the environment variable "MY_ENV" to "abc" for the execution of command.

What you want to do is store the output of  your command a variable, for this you'll need to use command substitutions:

```
my_var=$(command)
```

In your case:

```
route_id=$(jq -r '.[][]? | select(.pattern? == "test.com/testcards/email/").id' route.json)
```

Nitpicking; use lowercase variable names when possible, as UPPER_CASE are "reserved" for exported environment variables.